# Error using "select round" in WHERE filter

Tags: oracle

I need to do a "WHERE" filter in my code, like that:

```
    "select
    round ((aust.DTH_DESENFORNAMENTO - aust.dth_enfornamento),7)*1440 as HF

    from
    qt_qts.res_tubo_austenitizacao aust

   WHERE
   HF between 'time1' and 'time2' <----------------- THE ERROR
   ")
```

But it show that HF is not recognized in my code. So, i tried to put the full name (aust.DTH_DESENFORNAMENTO - aust.dth_enfornamento) and it worked... BUT, i need to put the full expression, what converts the time to seconds (((aust.DTH_DESENFORNAMENTO - aust.dth_enfornamento),7)*1440). That way, an error appear, cause of the expression.

I'm using ORACLE database

How can I refeer to the HF time with no error in my code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL not recognizing column alias in where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28802134/sql-not-recognizing-column-alias-in-where-clause) and [many other similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28802134/sql-not-recognizing-column-alias-in-where-clause).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aliases defined in a given `SELECT` clause are not available in the `WHERE` clause at the same level, because the latter is executed *before* the former.  You have two choices here: you may either repeat the expression to which you assigned the `HF` alias, or you can subquery.  Here is the first option:

```
SELECT
    ROUND((aust.DTH_DESENFORNAMENTO - aust.dth_enfornamento),7)*1440 AS HF
FROM qt_qts.res_tubo_austenitizacao aust
WHERE
    ROUND((aust.DTH_DESENFORNAMENTO - aust.dth_enfornamento),7)*1440
        BETWEEN 'time1' AND 'time2';
```

And here is the subquery option:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        ROUND((aust.DTH_DESENFORNAMENTO - aust.dth_enfornamento),7)*1440 AS HF
    FROM qt_qts.res_tubo_austenitizacao aust
)

SELECT HF
FROM cte
WHERE HF BETWEEN 'time1' AND 'time2';
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks.
I prefer the first option to clean the code. Really thanks.